# Audio Wave Form in React Native

Tags: react-native, waveform, audiowaveform

Im using react-native-audio-recorder-player to record voice, and i want to display audio like a wave, but I cannot find any dependency for it( React-native-audiowaveform doesn't work in latest React native version).

I tried to make a custom wave and sync it with my audio and it didn't sync properly as well. Is there any dependency that I can use to achieve this, or perhaps a combination of two?

Comment: same here any solution?

Comment: making ur own custom component is the only answer so far